# Global constants in F# - how to

Tags: f#, constants, c#-to-f#

I need to set a version number to be used in the AssemblyVersion attribute by several related projects.

In C# I use the following

```
public class Constants {
    public const string Version = "1.2.3.4";
}
```

then it can be used as follows:

```
[assembly:AssemblyVersion(Constants.Version)]
```

What would be the equivalent construct in F#. All my attempts to come up with a binding which can be accepted as an attribute argument did not work.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the attribute [`Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353581(VS.100).aspx):

```
[<Literal>] 
let version = "1.2.3.4"

[<assembly:AssemblyVersion(version)>]
```

Answer (score 9):

Since I stepped into this trap myself I thought I'd share for anyone following.
A 'Literal' requires that the letter starts with a capital letter. This will hit you when you try to use the literal in a pattern matching construct.

Reference:
[Literal attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890037/f-literal-attribute-not-working)

Comment: This is true only if you want to use the literal in a pattern matching context.

Comment: Pattern matching is pretty central to F#, though.  Not working in pattern matching makes it much less useful.

Comment: This answer would be better as a comment to the accepted answer.