# Global State in Functional Programming (F#)

Tags: functional-programming, f#, global-variables

I want to compute some functions which are dependent on some variables (specific data on which I run the code) and global variables, which are unlikely to be changed, but I want to leave them user-tunable. Just to clarify with an example, suppose I want to declare the following function:

```
let multiplyByGain x =
   x * gain
```

Where would you declare gain, being gain a global constant for the whole project. In a separate module with constants? That would couple the module with this code, though. Or would you use a curried version:

```
let multiblyByGain x gain =
   x * gain
```

and then specialize for the specific values? But suppose you have many functions like that, you will have to inject gain to all of them (in a sort of linking module)?

In my specific problem this becomes more cumbersome because both x and gain are arrays which must have the same length, suppose I have to do a Array.zip, e.g.: what is the best practice in terms of functional design to address a global constant, as gain, in a general way?

P.S.: I have found this old post[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326398/global-constants-in-f-how-to), but addresses only a specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single correct answer to the question and the best approach will depend on a variety of other constraints and requirements that you have. Also, it depends on whether you are asking specifically about F# or whether you are asking about functional programming more generally. I think there are three main points:

**Keeping it simple.**
Using a module that exposes `gain` as a global value, which has some initialization code to read configuration seems like a good default approach in F#. If this is changed only rarely (say, before you run the whole computation), then mutation is not going to cause you any troubles. You just need to be careful to avoid changing the values while some computation is still running. I think most F# programmers code tend to be quite pragmatic about this and this seems like the easiest thing to start with.

**Unit testing.**
If you want to unit ytest your `multiplyByGain` function with different `gain` as an argument, then you'll need some way of passing different values of `gain` to the function from your unit tests. In this case, having it as an additional parameter and using currying is nice, because you can just call it with other values of `gain` from your tests.

**Functional programming.**
Some functional language communities  (especially Haskell and, sometimes, Scala) are way more strict about state. The purely functional way of keeping state would be to use monads (either the reader monad or some kind of free monad structure). This makes your code a lot more complicated (both conceptually and in terms of extra syntactic overhead), but it is a purely functional solution that eliminates state. In F#, this kind of approach is even more cumbersome, so it's not very common.

Comment: Tomas, thanks a lot for the clear explanation. To answer your question: I was considering F# specifically, hoping in the best practice to solve the issue functionally. If I understand correctly most people would take advantage of the 'hybrid nature' of the language and use some kind of global parameter in a way or another. Cheers